# why output of char with two '+' is integer

Tags: java

I have question about my code in java. 
I have variable with type data char, with 2 plus '+',

why the result of the code is integer?

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {// kumpulan dari kata kata
        char exampleChar1;
        exampleChar1 = 'A';
        exampleChar1++;
        System.out.println("result of exampleChar1 is : " + + exampleChar1); // result is : result of exampleChar1 is : 66
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `char` can be seen as a type of integer.

The anatomy of your code is:
String Operator Cast Char

1. [String] "result of exampleChar1 is : "
2. [Operator] +
3. [Cast] + (this let the compiler thinks you like to calculate `0 + exampleChar1` and therefore casts it to an integer type)
4. [Char] exampleChar1

Just remove the second `+` and it should be fine.

```
System.out.println("result of exampleChar1 is : " + exampleChar1);
```

If this does not work, force a cast to char:

```
System.out.println("result of exampleChar1 is : " + (char) exampleChar1);
```